# In British English, do "university" & "school" have similar usages?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

Ok,

"**My children are at school**" means "**My children are attending a school**".

"**My son is at university**" means "**My son is attending a university**".
([Source](http://thefreedictionary.com/school))

So, "university" & "school" have this **similar** usage.

But "**school**" also has other usage,

> "**school**" also means "[uncountable] (used without the or a) the time
>   during the day when children are working in a school"
>
> Shall I meet you after school today?
>
> School begins at 9.
>
> The kids are at school until 3.30. (means "Right at this moment, my
>   children are at that school *in person*" & have not come back home yet) [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/school_1?q=school)

My question is:

does "**university**" mean "*(Uncountable Noun) the time during the day when students are working in a university*"

So, does  "**My son is at university until 3.30.**" mean "Right at this moment, my son is at that university *in person*" & has not come back home yet?

does "**shall I meet you after university**" mean "**shall I meet you after you finish your  university class today**"

Comment: No. The noun _University_ does not refer at all to a period of time. _University_ does **not** mean _"the time during the day when students are working in a university"._ But _"My son is at university until 3.30"_ **does** mean _"Right at this moment, my son is on the campus of the university in person and has not come back home yet."_ Your question is phrased very peculiarly. Can you clarify exactly what you imagine the noun _university_ to mean?

Comment: @P.E.Dant, I edited my questiom. I just want to know if "university" & "school" have similar usages.

Comment: What does your dictionary tell you about the noun?

Comment: @P.E.Dant, the dictionary only has 1 meaning for "university" ("an educational institution at the highest level, where you study for a degree"). But it also say "at university=studying at a university"

Comment: How does that definition conflict with the definition of _school?_

Comment: @P.E.Dant, I don't want to say "conflict" or "not conflict". I just want to know that whether they have similar usages. So, does "see you after university (after you finish your class at your university)" make sense?

Comment: It would make sense in the proper context, although it could be taken to mean _"I'll see you when your term is finished."_

Comment: I would take "see you after university" to mean "I'll see you after you graduate", but I'm from the US, so it may be different in the UK.

Comment: It is probably due to the difference in living arrangements that most students have compared to school children. They traditionally lived in far away from their parents homes and would not return everyday unlike schoolchildren who, unless they were at a boarding school would return home after school everyday. So after school means after the child has returned from school which happens everyday, after university refers to a far longer period of time. Some students now do stay at home but that is still a rarity.   I would agree that  "after university" means after graduation I am from the U.K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the usage of

> **at school**
>   **at university**

are analogous as referring to the time one is *studying* / *taking classes*, however

> **after school**
>   *Meet you today after school.*

is a commonly thought of *time of day*

> **after university**
>   *After university, I will bee seeking employment.*

would be more thought of as a *time of life*, more analogous might be

> **after classes**
>   *Meet your today after classes at the coffee shop.*

In common use BrE the shortened form of "**uni**" (*you-nee*) is often used.

**University** is a *type* / *form* of **schooling**.

Comment: This is a little misleading (from a British English point of view). To say "my daughter is at school" would imply (without more information) that she would return home later today. "My daughter is at university" would imply she had gone to university for the entire term - in other words it is not a time of day, but a period of days or weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *university* and *school* have similar uses - in most circumstances.

The reason why the use of *school* and *university* may differ is that the time spent there is structured differently. This means that the idiomatic use of *after school* and *after university* are different (try searching for them).

> **After school** - the time of the day after school has finished (see *after school clubs*, for example)
>   **After university** - the time after you have graduated from university

When attending school, students are in the school site between set hours that are always the same, and they generally can't leave during those hours. The teaching is all very structured and the school site is generally relatively small, and not where the students live (unless it's a boarding school). Therefore, during the day, there is a very definite *at school* and *not at school*.

University tends to be somewhat different. Often students will live on the university site, or in university owned accommodation. The teaching is much less structured (more of the time is self-study), is often less regular (one day lectures could be 9-11, the next may have no lectures, but a seminar from 2-4) and is generally more diverse (there are lectures, seminars, labs, etc). The site is much bigger and either will be dispersed throughout a city, or will make up a campus that a student might not leave very often (because they live there).

It therefore often doesn't make that much sense to say *"after university"* in the same way as *"after school"*, because that could mean many different things and refer to many different times. Many students will not consider themselves as *leaving university* at any point during the day. You are much more likely to hear *"after lectures"* or possibly *"after class"* (although I think of that as being more of an American phrase).  You might also hear something like *"See you after I've finished with uni (work) for the day"*.

That said, there is nothing to stop you from using *university* to mean *the time during the day during which someone is at university*, you would just have to make it clear from the context that that's what you mean. It would generally require more explanation than saying "after school" would, and there is probably a better way of saying it.